# Divide polynomials and conclude:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to divide $x^3-a^3$ by $x-a$ and conclude that $x^3 - a^3 = (x-a)*(x^2+ax+a^2)$, but, I'm not sure about how to divide this polynomials, basically doing what I think I should do I will get just "$x^2+a^2$", from where in the division came the "$ax$"?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the steps you used to reach $x^2+a^2$, so that people can show where the mistake was?

Comment: Your question is on how to divide polynomials. Check out this resource for polynomial long division:
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydiv2.htm

Comment: @ZevChonoles i think he divide $x^3$by x and $a^3$ by a

Comment: Yes, @iostream007, basically that. I know it's not right and I'm trying to figure out how to do it. Here http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nOVgRO7w1vs/TxzALeKUnnI/AAAAAAAAASA/3a0cjHZ21sw/s1600/4.jpg there is a resolution of this same question but I'm still do not understand the "ax" on the division.

Comment: actually we can divide those terms which is only multiplicated with other terms.like in this case $x^3$ and $a^3$ has added so we can not divide them now

Answer (score 1):

Division of polynomials works a lot like the division of integers (more formally, like the integers, we can divide using a Euclidean algorithm).

Hence, to divide $x^{3}-a^{3}$ by $x-a$, we find the largest multiplicative factor that we can multiply the remainder by, and subtract it as follows until we get a remainder of $0$, or a term having degree smaller than the original divisor. The sum of the multiplicative factors will be the quotient:

$$x^{3} - a^{3} = x^{2}(x-a) + r_{1}(x)$$
$$\implies r_{1}(x) = ax^{2} - a^{3}$$
$$ax^{2}-a^{3} = ax(x-a) + r_{2}(x)$$
$$\implies r_{2}(x) = a^{2}x - a^{3}$$
$$a^{2}x - a^{3} = a^{2}(x-a) + r_{3}(x)$$
$$\implies r_{3}(x) = 0$$

Since our remainder is now 0, we have completely factored the expression. Thus, we get $x^{3} - a^{3} = (x^{2} + ax + a^{2})(x-a)$.

Answer (score 1):

here some prove i think you want to see this
$$(x-a)^3=x^3-y^3-3xa(x-a)$$
$$(x-a)^3+3xa(x-a)=x^3-y^3$$
$$(x-a)((x-a)^2+3xa)=x^3-y^3$$
$$(x-a)((x^2+a^2-2xa+3xa)=x^3-y^3$$
$$(x-a)((x^2+a^2+xa)=x^3-y^3$$

now we have value of   $x^3-y^3$ and we want to divide it (x-a).
so
$$\frac{(x-a)((x^2+a^2+xa)}{(x-a)}$$
clearly (x-a) is cancelling out above (x-a)
so answer will be
$$x^2+a^2+xa$$